# Unable to show local notification in flutter. Tried following the documents followed by several tutorial

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

This is how i am trying to use local notification. But when clicking on button the notification is not showing.
Not getting any error also.

This is how i am calling show notification.

```
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  await service.showNotification(id: 1, title: 'x', body: 'x');
                },
                child: Text("Send")),
```

My Service Class:

```
class LocalNotificationService {
  LocalNotificationService();

  final _localNotificationService = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  Future<void> initialize() async {
    const AndroidInitializationSettings androidInitializationSettings =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('logo');

    const InitializationSettings settings = InitializationSettings(
      android: androidInitializationSettings,
    );

    await _localNotificationService.initialize(settings);
  }

  Future<NotificationDetails> _notificationsDetails() async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      '1', // Replace with your channel ID
      'x', // Replace with your channel name
      channelDescription: 'description',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.max,
      playSound: true,
    );

    return const NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);
  }

  Future<void> showNotification({
    required int id,
    required String title,
    required String body,
  }) async {
    final details = await _notificationsDetails();
    await _localNotificationService.show(id, title, body, details);
    print("hi");
  }

  void onSelectNotification(String? payload) {
    print('payload $payload');
  }
}
```

Also calling the **`initialize`** method of **`LocalNotificationService`** class before trying to show notifications.

Answer (score 0):

you want to show local notifications in Flutter,

I have written a blog on `Local Notifications in Flutter`  [Link to my blog](https://priyanshupaliwal.hashnode.dev/local-notifications-in-flutter),

you can follow the blog and it will guide you fully on `how to show local notifications in Flutter`.

Comment: Thanks for support. I got the fix. 

I was focusing only coding. And finally found that the notification was blocked in settings.